# How to add filter to Container for deleting blobs except some blobs in a virtual folder?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azureportal, azure-storage-account

I am having set of folders in container named records (Azure storage account). In general what ever the blobs(folders) present in records container it will be deleted as per lifecycle management rule.

**Rule**: if blob exists more than 30days than it will delete the blob.

But As per my case, All blobs (folders) should delete except one blob (folder) where the blob(folder) name is `Backup` in the container.

Is there any way to add a rule for not deleting particular blob(In my case it is folder)?
[image]
So backup folder shouldn't delete when the existing rule run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a lease for the particular blob using the azure portal for example. A lease prevents processes from doing anything with the blob. This includes lifecycle management rules.

[image]

You can also acquire or break a lease using the [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob) or one of the many [storage SKDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=environment-variable-windows).

Another option would be to not use the lifecycle management rules but write a scheduled azure function that deletes blob older than 30 days except the ones having `backup` in their name.

Please do note: if you have enabled ["Hierarchical namespace"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-namespace) then you have the concept of directories, but those cannot be leased. If you did not then you should realise that folders are a virtual construct and as such cannot be leased as they are actually blobs. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list#flat-listing-versus-hierarchical-listing). So in that case you have to individually take a lease on each blob or write a script that does it once.

Comment: Is it possible to create lease for a particular folder inside the container? I am having folders inside the container not the files, I want to avoid particular folder to delete?

Comment: @akhil If you have enabled ["Hierarchical namespace"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-namespace) then you have the concept of directories,  but those cannot be leased. If you did not then you should realise that folders are a virtual construct and as such cannot be leased as they are actually blobs. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list#flat-listing-versus-hierarchical-listing). So in that case you have to individually take a lease on each blob or write a script that does it once

Comment: I have wrote some rule using life cycle management, But I want to test immediately. If you know Can you please guide me to test the rule immediately?

Comment: As far as I know that is not possible

Comment: @akhil please see my updated answer for an alternative